Transferring textures and uv to a new image map without baking using python
Me and my team are working on a project where it wouldn't be possible to rebake textures from old uv map to a new one, so one of us has managed to make a python code where it stores pixels that are iccupied by previous uv, and then moves them to a new image packing the pixels accordingly. But we can't imagine how to do same thing for the ups. Do you guys have any ideas?
    log("Получение используемых областей текстуры")
    uv_layer = obj.data.uv_layers.active.data
    texture_regions = []

    for poly in obj.data.polygons:
        poly_uv = [uv_layer[li].uv for li in poly.loop_indices]
        x_coords = [int(uv.x * texture_image.size[0]) for uv in poly_uv]
        y_coords = [int(uv.y * texture_image.size[1]) for uv in poly_uv]
        min_x, max_x = min(x_coords), max(x_coords)
        min_y, max_y = min(y_coords), max(y_coords)
        texture_regions.append((min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y))

    return texture_regions 

That's part of our code where a guy used bounding boxes to know which pixels to take, then he stores them as numpy array, and moves the pixels to the right spots. Unfortunately I'm not sure I can share the whole code :(

OK, so you need baking and you know you do, so why can't you use it?

cause we need python as it will be used in three.js and rebaking it would take lots of computing on server, which nobody here wants :(
baking would be so easy

Well, you will need to do same computations in any case. If it's only for remapping textures for another UV map, you don't need to calculate lighting or many samples at all... I really see no problem there to do things the way they are done to be honest.
